# impulse response for a series RLC circuit

Tags: passive-networks

How I can solve this?  The impulse response of Vc is wanted.

[image: schematic]

I have problem with current in right mesh and I can't write it by Vc or ... . Here is my attempt:

[image: my attempt]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have too many currents.

Replaying currents ...

i1, i2 are the currents into meshes (left, right) .
Seems that your equations are "ok" ... but difficult to "read" ...

Here is a Maple sheet with the 3 basic equations (Laplace functions) and solutions.

[image]

I have also made a circuit simulation with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110).

[image]